How to replace a word in whole workspace? I am using Spring Tool Suite IDE
I am working on a project and suddenly I realize I mis-spelled the word "category" to "catagory" on almost every place- within my workspace.
It there any way to replace all occurrences of "catagory" in one shot?

Ok i find that answer.
I need to use internationalization concept in my application and i have to make sure all the text used in my project will come form from one of more language configuration files.
example
resources/lang/messages.properties
something-went-wrong=Something went wrong!
success-created=Item Created Successfully!

so now i can access the value using keys something-went-wrong and success-created
Benifits :

whenever i need to change any string, I can change them form one centeralized place.
Ignore hardcoded text
It will useful when i try to use multilanguage support in my application

